# Convolution: Give a proof that $f_T(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(t-x)dx$ where $f_T(t)$ is the PDF of random variable T

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution

Here is the question:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, continuous r.v.s with PDFs $f_X$ and $f_Y$ respectively, and let $T=X+Y$. Find the join PDF of $T$ and $X$, and use this to give a proof that $f_T(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(t-x)dx$.

Here is my attempt:

> First find the CDF of $X,T$:
>   \begin{align}
> F_{X,T}(x,t)
> &=P(X\leq x,T \leq t)\\
> &=P(X\leq x,X+Y \leq t)\\
> &=P(X\leq x,Y \leq t-X)\\
> &=P(X\leq x,Y \leq t-x)\\
> &=P(X\leq x)P(Y \leq t-x)\\
> &=F_X(x)F_Y(t-x)
> \end{align}
>
> Thus, we can get the PDF by taking the derivative with respect to $t$:
>   \begin{align}
> f_{X,T}(x,t)
> &=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial t}F_{X,T}(x,t)\\
> &=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(F_X(x)f_Y(t-x))
> \end{align}
>
> To get the PDF of $T$:
>   \begin{align}
> f_T(t)
> &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(F_X(x)f_Y(t-x))dx\\
> &=F_X(x)f_Y(t-x)
> \end{align}

This clearly is not the convolution, does anyone know why this is wrong?

**EDIT**

Alright, so turns out I just forgot to evaluate the integral. Then, suppose I did this:
$$f_T(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(F_X(x)f_Y(t-x))dx$$

Apply chain rule and we get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f_X(x)f_Y(t-x)+F_X(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_Y(t-x))dx$$

Now this almost looks like the convolution, is the second term some how zero or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not quite sure, but I think your error is $P(X \le x, Y \le t-X) = P(X \le x, Y \le t-x)$. The most you can say here is "$\le$"; I don't think equality holds.

---

It suffices to show $f_{X,T}(x,t) = f_X(x) f_Y(t-x)$; then, integrating over $x$ gives the desired form of $f_T(t)$.

*My computation below is a little unrigorous because I condition on an event $\{X=u\}$ that has zero probability.* This issue can be resolved (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability#Example) for example), but **I am curious if others have a better way of presenting this computation.**

\begin{align}
P(X \le x, X+Y \le t)
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X \le x, X+Y \le t \mid X=u) f_X(u) \mathop{du}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^x P(Y \le t-u) f_X(u) \mathop{du}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^x F_Y(t-u) f_X(u) \mathop{du}\\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial t}P(X \le x, X+Y \le t)
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} F_Y(t-x) f_X(x)\\
f_{X,T}(x,t) &= f_Y(t-x) f_X(x).
\end{align}

Comment: Wait, so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X \leq x \mid X=u)f_X(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(u)$? What does $P(X \leq x \mid X=u)$ even mean?

Comment: One more question is how did you get from line 3 to line 4? How did you get rid of the integral, if you can explain this to me that would be awesome!

Comment: @ZoomBee The integral disappears by applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I think $P(X \le x \mid X=u)$ is $1$ if $u \le x$ and zero otherwise. I suggest you check out copper.hat's answer, as it avoids this messy business of conditioning.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
P [ X+Y \le \alpha] &=&\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty 1_{\{(x,y) | x+y \le \alpha \}} ((x,y)) f_X(x) f_Y(y)dy dx \\
&=& \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \int_{y=-\infty}^{\alpha-x}  f_X(x) f_Y(y) dy dx \\
&=& \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \int_{y=-\infty}^{\alpha}  f_X(x) f_Y(y-x) dy dx \\
&=& \int_{y=-\infty}^{\alpha}  \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty  f_X(x) f_Y(y-x) dy dx \\
&=& \int_{y=-\infty}^{\alpha}  f_T(y) dy \\
\end{eqnarray}
where $f_T(t) = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty  f_X(x) f_Y(t-x) dx$

Answer (score 1):

Following your initial lines, 
\begin{multline*}
F_{X,T}(x,t) 
= P(X\le x, T\le t)
= P(X\le x, X+Y\le t)
= P(X\le x, X+Y\le t - X) \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{x} P(X\le x, X+Y\le t - X|X=z) f_X(z) dz
= \int_{-\infty}^{x} P(z\le x, Y\le t - z|X=z) f_X(z) dz \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{x} P(Y\le t - z|X=z) f_X(z) dz 
= \int_{-\infty}^{x} P(Y\le t - z) f_X(z) dz \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{x} F_Y(t-z) f_X(z) dz.
\end{multline*}

Now recall that $F_T(t) = \lim_{x\to\infty} F_{X,T}(x,t)$ and apply it on the above:
\begin{multline*}
F_T(t) 
= \lim_{x\to\infty} F_{X,T}(x,t)
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{x} F_Y(t-z) f_X(z) dz \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_Y(t-z) f_X(z) dz
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_Y(t-x) f_X(x) dx.
\end{multline*}

Now $f_T(t) = F_T'(t)$, 
so, skipping lazily all due justifications, we have
\begin{multline*}
f_T(t) 
= \frac{d}{dt} F_T(t)
= \frac{d}{dt} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_Y(t-x) f_X(x) dx\right)
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{d}{dt} F_Y(t-x)\right) f_X(x) dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\left(
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} F_Y(t-x) \frac{d}{dt} (t-x) \right)
f_X(x) dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
f_Y(t-x) f_X(x) dx,
\end{multline*}
as intended initially.

Answer (score 0):

the last step is wrong.
you are integrating over $x$, so the end result of the (definite) integral does not depend on $x$. looks like you forgot to evaluate it.

Comment: Hmmm, if that is the case, I decided to apply the chain rule to the inside and it sort of looks like the convolution but not exactly. I updated my question, do you know if the second term is zero or I made a mistake?